# PHP: why does session_encode() cutoff output?

Tags: php, string, postgresql, session

I think the root of the problem is my understanding of string handling. `serialize($_SESSION)` does the same thing. My session file goes on for 5kb, but when I output `session_encode()` to the log or to a database, it cuts off after about 100 bytes.

```
    $s = session_encode();
    $n = strlen($s);
    error_log("Session ($n): $s");
```

I get:

> Session (5948): return_url|s:30:"https://solution-locale/Moneys";complete|s:0:"";basket|O:15:"SolutionUBasket":22:{s:13:

When I try writing the value to the database (`pg_execute()`--that's a prepared statement) I get the same problem. But when I do a `bin2hex()`, I learn that after that last ":" there's a null character (0x00).

So clearly the problem is string handling, and I'm not doing it right.

And the db-writing code is the following:

```
pg_prepare($this->getCnx(), $token, $sql);
pg_execute($this->getCnx(), $token, $values);
```

`$sql` is:

> UPDATE "solution_ubasket_temp" SET ("session_id", "session", "id") = ($1, $2, $3) WHERE "id"=$4"

`$values` is just an array. `strlen()` operations on it confirms that all 5kb get into the session member.

The update goes ahead without error messages, but the "session" field gets cut off just like the in the debug.

```
select length(session), * from solution_ubasket_temp
```

confirms that "session" gets cutoff after 105 bytes.

The "session" column is a `text` but changing it to a `bytea` didn't help.

```
select octet_length(session), * from solution_ubasket_temp
```

confirms that.

I'm running PHP 5.6 on Debian 8.5.

Comment: The PHP manual warns you for the `error_log` function: `Warning
error_log() is not binary safe. message will be truncated by null character.` (http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php)

Comment: @JeremyHarris No, I'm never given that warning

Comment: It says *5948*, so the return value of `session_encode` isn't the problem…

Comment: @Opux The warning is written on the php manual page.

Comment: @Opux Basicly, yes. Better do by yourself.

Comment: Also, with postgres, you apparently CAN write a null byte. It may be the prepared statement is escaping something wrong. https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/49F5F02A.1070505@networkmail.eu

Comment: How about post `var_dump("Session ($n): $s");` ??

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Actually, the problem runs a little deeper than that. It seems the object in question is `SolutionUBasket` and that object *does* have `__sleep()` and `__wakeup()` and the members it directs to serialize in `__sleep()` are POD.

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions `var_dump("Session ($n): $s");` didn't work so well, but maybe what you're looking for is `error_log(var_export("Session ($n): $s", true));`. So, trying that one, it no longer cuts off at "...{s:13:" but continues w/"...' . "\\0" ....`. But I wouldn't know how to deserialize that.

Comment: Not sure this has been spelled out clearly enough, so to avoid going off in the wrong direction here: the serialised data contains a `NUL` byte. That is in itself not a problem that requires fixing. Only: 1) `error_log` in particular cannot correctly deal with `NUL` bytes, which is why your debugging method fails; 2) Postgres *can* deal with `NUL` bytes just fine *if you handle them correctly.* You'll have to show us what exactly you're doing with `pg_execute` for us to help you with that part of the problem.

Comment: Session & Object & _wakeup() & _sleep() ...  thing you should open a new question for that :)

Comment: @deceze Done...

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Maybe I will... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288501/php-postgresql-writing-binary-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the question was wrong. It's not a matter of `session_encode()` cutting it off, but the fact that some PHP routines might not be able to handle the binary strings that the function produces. So, bottom line: if you use `session_encode()`, make sure whatever routines that handle the return value can deal w/it. So far, I've found that `error_log()` and `pg_execute()` cannot.

This was made clearer here: [PHP/PostgreSQL: writing binary data with prepared statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41288501/php-postgresql-writing-binary-data-with-prepared-statements)