# PHP/PostgreSQL: writing binary data with prepared statements

Tags: php, postgresql, prepared-statement, binary-data

I've been using `pg_prepare()` and `pg_execute()` very reliably for a long time now, but now that I'm writing binary data to it, I've run into difficulties.

I was surprised to learn that `session_encode()` returns NULL values in its strings, but have always been told that you don't need to escape data in prepared statements. So why when I write a 5kb field to the db, does it cut off after about 100 bytes?

If I execute:

```
UPDATE "solution_ubasket_temp" SET ("session_id", "session", "id") = ($1, $2, $3) WHERE "id"=$4"
```

and set the 2nd member of the input array to the 5kb return value of `session_encode()`, it cuts off after the first NULL value it finds.

```
select octet_length(session), * from solution_ubasket_temp
```

confirms that there are only 105 bytes stored in "session" which are:

> return_url|s:30:"https://solution-locale/Moneys";complete|s:0:"";basket|O:15:"SolutionUBasket":22:{s:13:

`bin2hex()` confirms that the next byte after that string is a NULL.

Making "session" a `text` or `bytea` makes no difference.

I tried Googling for things like "php postgresql prepared statements binary" but I just got a lot of hits about MySQL and http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-php/postgresql-blob/ but that uses something called "PDO" and I don't know what that is.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-execute.php doesn't have this text, but from http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php:

> Values intended for bytea fields are not supported as parameters. Use pg_escape_bytea() instead, or use the large object functions.

might give a hint. Maybe I'm supposed to be using `bytea` instead of `text` and call `pg_escape_bytea()`.

The table I'm working w/:

```
CREATE TABLE solution_ubasket_temp
(
  session_id character varying(40) NOT NULL,
  session text,
  last_update timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  order_id integer,
  status character varying(2),
  email character varying(100),
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('solution_ubasket_temp_id_seq1'::regclass),
  CONSTRAINT solution_ubasket_temp_id_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX solution_ubasket_temp_email_index
  ON solution_ubasket_temp
  USING btree
  (email COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX solution_ubasket_temp_session_id_index
  ON solution_ubasket_temp
  USING btree
  (session_id COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

I'm running PHP 5.6 on Debian 8.5 and PostgreSQL 9.4.

Comment: base64_encode before insert, and decode on read

Comment: @cake I guess I'll have to, if there's nothing else better customized. Hopefully I'll never be in a situation where I have to store a large amount of binary data, in which case, I guess I'll be learning about stored procedures maybe

Comment: @cske that's not the way to do it.

Comment: please post your table. I'll show you how to do it with PDO.

Comment: @e4c5 You can ignore most of the columns right now and if necessary "session" could be changed to another type

Comment: right thanks. BTW, you were not inserting into the email column due to a typo by any chance? That column is exactly a 100 chars (which may or may not be 100 bytes)

Comment: @e4c5 I'm not sure what you're asking. The email is limited to 100 chars, because if we need more than that, we'll deal w/it then. But right now we're not even using it. We will as the project develops.

Comment: Did you try my answer?

Comment: @e4c5 Not while I'm on vacay. But before I left, my boss told me that PDO is not adequate for our needs, and can't be justified for this single role. But if things change we can circle back to it and give it a try

Comment: "not adequate"? Wonder what the boss is smoking. PDO is the most upto date and most powerfull of the PHP databsase APIs. So you can say pg_* or mysqli_* is not adquate but PDO!!??

Answer (score 1):

### Using PDO

To effectively insert/update text or binary to your table, you need to use PDO, this is what the code might look like.

```
<?php
$dbh = new PDO('pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=test_rideshare', "postgres");

$fdata = file_get_contents('/tmp/sample.txt');
$n = 11;


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO solution_ubasket_temp(session_id,session,order_id) Values(?,?,?) ");
$stmt->bindParam(1,$n);
$stmt->bindParam(2,$fdata, PDO::PARAM_LOB);
$stmt->bindParam(3,$n);


$stmt->execute();
print $stmt->debugDumpParams();
print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
print_r($dbh->errorInfo());


$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT session FROM solution_ubasket_temp LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$a = $stmt->fetch();
print_r($a);

file_put_contents("/tmp/sample2.txt",$a['session']);

?>
```

The above code sample shows how to do an insert and then read the data again. It also writes the same data to another file for comparison. Visual or diff comparison will show that they are the same.

For update, just replace the insert statement with an update statement

### Binary Data

If you are storing binary data, you should use a binary field. That is

```
session bytea,
```

In fact, I never use text fields, when ever I have the need to store large objects I choose binary and whenever possible I try to avoid storing large objects in the db. In fact though my code above demonstrates how to store a file in the DB. this is something that I would never do in production.

### PHP Serialize vs JSON

You data looks like it's serialized PHP. May I suggest that you switch to JSON instead and store the data in an [JSONB](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html) field instead? That would give you many more options than PHP serialize and deserialize, not to mention that mention the fact that JSON is supported in almost any programming language while using PHP serialize would lock you down to PHP.